# How to disable labelname.tabindex?

Tags: winforms

I am using winform application and I want to disable the label's tabindex. I don't want the focus to be on label when I hit my tab key. How to do that??

Comment: Setting the Tab-Index as per you required will give you the solution

Comment: actually labels are in the panel.. and below panel there is another checkbox.. so I want the tab button on hitting to skip label and go to checkbox...

Comment: Ya that's what i am saying check the Tab-index of Label or set Check-box Tab-index to 0 or 1

Answer (score 7):

This is fairly miraculous.  Getting the tabbing to stop at a label is very hard, it doesn't want the focus.  Its constructor sets the TabStop property to false.  What is even harder is *seeing* that the label has the focus, it doesn't have any way to indicate it.  Which begs the question how you know that the label got the focus.

Triple check this, you might be mis-interpreting what is really going on.  Like having the wrong TabIndex value on the rest of the controls.  View + Tab Order is a very handy designer command that makes the tabbing order easy to see and modify.

Comment: +1 for view -> taborder, -1 to me for having to work on winforms in 2014 :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the default set to false. When I create a label I get the following in the formname.designer.cs

```
// 
            // lblEntitlement
            // 
            this.lblEntitlement.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblEntitlement.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(103, 68);
            this.lblEntitlement.Name = "lblEntitlement";
            this.lblEntitlement.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 18);
            this.lblEntitlement.TabIndex = 8;
            this.lblEntitlement.Text = "NA";
```

there does not appears to be any default setting of the tabstop here

what I would do is to create a recursive loop and iterate over the controls on the form and for each label set the tabstop to false. Maybe make a form that doe this and have all your other forms inherit from that. I am sure there a opinions about this (maybe some of the purists will say your losing a 100th of a second when loading the form but the trade off is definitely worth it for me)

example

```
private void DisableTabstops(Control.ControlCollection controls)
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
            {

                if (control.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    control.TabStop = false;
                }


                if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    DisableTabstops(control.Controls);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Not in the auto generated configuration code, but if you look at the constructor for Label you see the line `TabStop = false;` https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs

Answer (score 2):

The tabstop property on a label is already defaulted to false, you should not have to do anything. If tabstop is set to true, then you may have code somewhere which is setting this.

It seems that TabStop is not available directly on the Label class, to set it you would need to cast the object as a System.Windows.Forms.Control

Comment: Text search - ".TabStop = false"