# How to disable TabIndex?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to disable TabIndex for controls in a Form (C# winForms) that never need focus?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8919844/193513 you can then expand the type to Button or whatever you do not wish to ever get a tabstop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable a tab index on a control on a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271388/how-do-i-disable-a-tab-index-on-a-control-on-a-form)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Set [`TabStop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx) property to false

Answer (score 5):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.TabStop = false;
    }
```